# iPad - erase data completely

Tags: ipad, privacy, secure-erase

I am selling my old iPad 4, in which I stored some private data. I have done erasing my iPad data and settings, is it true that all my data is really gone and completely unrecoverable?

If not, what else should I do to make sure my data is unseen by the buyer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data on an iOS device [3GS & later] is protected by hardware encryption.

Wiping the device using Apple's guide at [What to do before selling or giving away your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351) is quite sufficient.

Extract :

> - If you paired an Apple Watch with your iPhone, [unpair your Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204568).
> - [Back up your iOS device](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT203977).
> - Tap Settings > iCloud. Scroll down and tap Sign Out. In iOS 7 or earlier, tap Delete Account.
> - Tap Sign Out again, then tap Delete from My iPhone and enter your password.
> - Go back to Settings and tap General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings. * If you turned on Find My iPhone, you might need to enter your Apple ID and password.
> - If asked for your device passcode or Restrictions passcode, enter it. Then tap Erase [device].
> - Contact your carrier for help transferring service to a new owner. If you aren't using a SIM card with your device, you can contact them to get help transferring service to the new owner.

See also : Apple KB - [iOS: Understanding data protection](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202064)
On recent iOS the setting is under Touch ID & Passcode.